# A commutative ring with unit element, which only has a finite number of ideals, is a field

Tags: ring-theory, proof-verification, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit element. Suppose that it only has a finite number of ideals. Show that it is a field

My reasoning is as follows:

Let $a \in R-\{0\}$. Since $R$ is a commutative ring, it can be shown that $Ra$ is an ideal of $R$. It follows that $Ra^n$ is also an ideal of $R$, for every $n \in \mathbb N^*$, and $Ra \supset Ra^2 ... \supset Ra^n \supset ...$. But $R$ only has a finite number of ideals, so there must exists $m \in \mathbb N^*$ such that $Ra^n=Ra^{n+1}=(Ra)a^n$, for every $n \geq m$.

Now, $(Ra)a^n=\{(ba)a^n,b \in R\}$. If $ba \neq 1, \forall b \in R \Rightarrow 1a^n \notin (Ra)a^n = Ra^n \Rightarrow$ contradiction because $1 \in R$. In other words, there exists $b \in R$ such that $ba=1$, or $R$ is a field.

Is my reasoning correct? Can we conclude that: $R=Ra$, and thus $R=Ra^n$, for every $n \in \mathbb N^*$?

Comment: But what about $\mathbb Z_6$? wouldn't the ring have to be a domain or something like that?

Comment: This could not possibly be true, as it would say all finite commutative rings with units are fields, which is patently false

Comment: So you mean, the problem is not correctly stated?

Comment: If I change $R$ to **infinite** commutative ring, will it be a correct question?

Comment: I would advise you to consider the chain $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \supseteq 3 \cdot \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \supseteq 3^2 \cdot \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \dots$. Then actually $3 \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} = 3^2\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. Now it is true that $b \cdot 3 \neq 1$ for all $b \in \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, but still $3  \in 3 \cdot\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. You seem to be assuming you are working over an integral domain.

Comment: Do you mean infinite as in an infite number of elements? Then consider the commutative ring $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thanks! So the question is incorrectly posed. Can it be modified in order to be correct?

Comment: Every artinian integral domain is a field. Your ring is artinian as it has finitely many ideals. So if you add the condition that it be an integral domain then the statement is true, otherwise you have seen counterexamples.

Comment: In fact every artinian integral domain is a field via an argument very similar to yours.

Comment: @Improve,@dReaM: thanks a lot! Actually I haven't learned about artinian stuff yet but at least for now, I know how the question should be. :)

Comment: An artinian ring is one such that whenever you have ideals $I_1 \supseteq I_2 \supseteq I_3 \dots $, then eventually $I_n = I_{n+1}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, which is exactly what you are using here.

Answer (score 3):

You must add that $R$ does not have zero divisor if not $Z/n\times Z/m$ is a counterexample.

Comment: do you mean $Z/mZ \times Z/nZ$?

Answer (score 2):

The last implication in your reasoning supposes $a^n\ne 0$, which is not necessarily true. If it were true, it would imply any finite ring is a field.

*Counter-example:*

$\mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z$ is definitely not a field. It has $6$ elements, and *a fortiori* a finite number of ideals.

Comment: Ah I see. What if I impose $R$ to be **infinite**?

Comment: I think if $ R$ is infinite then $\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Q $ is a counterexample.

Comment: Or $K[X]/(X^2)$, $K$ any field.